# How to set filter/criteria on unnamed object in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some long ugly data manipulation routine done in one line, for instance

```
xxx = pd.concat([comp, companies_src[companies_src.hash_inn.isin(counterparts12.inn_ctpt.unique())]], axis=0, sort=False)
```

then I want to apply filter to it

```
xxx_fitered = xxx[xxx.some_field==1]
```

how can I do it in one line of code? E.g. how can I reference the unnamed object before I assign it to xxx variable?

Comment: this seems like an XY problem. why are you trying to do this?

Comment: `xxx = pd.concat(...).query('some_field==1')`?

Comment: great thanks. I didn't know about query word